# Django with FastCGI gives 404 in browser but works on command line

Tags: python, django, apache, .htaccess, fastcgi

## Summary

Django 1.6
Python 2.6
Apache 2.2.27
PostgreSQL 8.4.20
psycopg2
flup

Viewing the FastCGI wrapper page for my Django site via the command line seems to work fine, but I always get a `404: Page Not Found` when viewing my site via a browser.  What am I doing wrong?  I suspect it has to do with my Apache setup.

## Versions and Setup

The Django 1.8 documentation says fastcgi support is deprecated as of Django 1.7, and I can't use `mod_wsgi`, so I am using Django 1.6.  Python 2.7 and later are unavailable, so I am using Python 2.6.  And the hosting company won't install Python packages for me, but I managed to install flup and psycopg2 myself.  (Note that I had to compile psycopg2 on my Linux64 machine and upload it to the server.)

Django, flup, and psycopg2 are installed in `/home/account/public_html/sitename/site-packages/`.  My Django site is located in `/home/account/public_html/sitename/sitename/`.  Issuing `set | grep -e PYTHON -e DJANGO` at the command prompt returns no results (i.e., no PYTHON or DJANGO environment variables are set).

## Full Story

I am trying to set up Django on shared hosting.  And before anyone suggests it: unfortunately, **`mod_wsgi` is out of the question**.

I followed the directions here:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#apache-shared-hosting  and ended up with this `/home/account/public_html/.htaccess`:

```
AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sitename/site.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

and this `/home/account/public_html/sitename/site.fcgi`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os

# Add a custom Python path.
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/account/public_html/sitename")
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/account/public_html/sitename/site-packages")

# Switch to the directory of your project. (Optional.)
os.chdir("/home/account/public_html/sitename")

# Set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable.
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "sitename.settings"

# From Django
from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="prefork", daemonize="false", debug="true")
```

When I do `cd /home/account/public_html/sitename/ ; ./site.fcgi`, I get:

```
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param REQUEST_METHOD required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_NAME required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PORT required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!
Status: 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...etc...
```

which is the correct index page for my Django site.  **So that works.**  (I am ignoring the WSGIServer errors for now, because calling `site.fcgi` from the command prompt is, obviously, outside the WSGI environment.)

However, when I navigate my browser to `http://example.com/`, I get a `404: Page Not Found` error, and the server error log shows only:

```
[error] File does not exist: /home/account/public_html/sitename/site.fcgi/
```

Navigating to `http://example.com/valid-page` also produces a `404`, with the server error:

```
[error] File does not exist: /home/account/public_html/sitename/site.fcgi/valid-page
```

What am I doing wrong?  Or how does WSGI work, so I can debug this better?

## Variations I've Tried

1. Use the HostGator approach to `site.fcgi` by doing this instead:

   ```
   # From Django
   #from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
   #runfastcgi(method="prefork", daemonize="false", debug="true")

   # From HostGator
   from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
   from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
   WSGIServer(get_wsgi_application()).run()
   ```

   Same result: `404`.  This makes sense, because manually walking the code shows that the `From Django` code is just a wrapper for the `From HostGator` code.
2. Use the `fcgid-script` handler in `.htaccess` instead of `fastcgi-script`:

   ```
   #AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
   AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
   ```
3. Use a `RewriteCond` in `.htaccess` that I found in another tutorial:

   ```
   #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(sitename/site.fcgi)
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sitename/site.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
   ```
4. Pass the WSGI URI as command-prompt-style parameter (note the space instead of `/`):

   ```
   #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sitename/site.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sitename/site.fcgi $1 [QSA,L]
   ```
5. Ensure the `REQUEST_URI` environment variable is set:

   ```
   SetEnv REQUEST_URI %{REQUEST_URI}
   ```
6. Even make `site.fcgi` a CGI script, just to see if I could reproduce the success of running `site.fcgi` from the command prompt (probably not a permanent solution):

   ```
   #AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
   #RewriteEngine On
   #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sitename/site.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
   Options -Indexes +ExecCGI
   AddHandler cgi-script .fcgi
   ```

   and then navigating to `http://example.com/sitename/site.fcgi`.

None of the above variations worked, nor did many combinations of several of them.  Many of them returned `404: Page Not Found`, and some returned more glaring errors, while others just displayed the source of `site.fcgi`.

## Edit

1. I am getting the same/similar results for shared hosting with both Arvixe and LunarPages.  The above description is using only my Arvixe account, because my LunarPages account does not have SSH access and is therefore harder to debug.

   I'd even be willing to entertain low-cost alternative hosting plans (e.g., other hosting companies) that would enable this to work.  This is just a personal website, not generating any money, so I don't want to spend the ~$20/month that Arvixe and LunarPages are asking to have dedicated hosting in order to have `mod_wsgi` access.

*Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!*

Comment: So hard to emulate, can you privide the ssh access? at least what shared hosting do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem (posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53474157/django-2-0-7-with-fastcgi-gives-404-in-browser-but-works-on-command-line/53695974#53695974)) and ended up determining that it was due to restrictions on the shared hosting account I was subscribed to with bluehost.  I switched a dreamhost shared hosting plan and was up and running in no time.